# error while installing ros from source on ubuntu arm

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, ubuntu, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, Although the website provides methods installing ros on arm, it is an armhf version of Ubuntu .However,I use an armel  version of Ubuntu.So I want to install ros from source on the  armel  version of Ubuntu  according to this page http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Source
When I excute

```
$ rosinstall_generator ros_comm --rosdistro groovy --deps --wet-only > groovy-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall
```

there was an error as follows,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall_generator", line 141, in <module>
    rc = main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall_generator", line 129, in main
    upstream_version_tag=args.upstream, upstream_source_version=args.upstream_development)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall_generator/generator.py", line 247, in generate_rosinstall
    wet_package_names, unreleased_repo_names = _get_packages_for_repos(distro_name, repo_names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall_generator/generator.py", line 93, in _get_packages_for_repos
    wet_distro = get_wet_distro(distro_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall_generator/generator.py", line 213, in get_wet_distro
    _wet_distro = _get_wet_distro(distro_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall_generator/distro.py", line 45, in get_distro
    return get_cached_distribution(index, distro_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdistro/__init__.py", line 134, in get_cached_distribution
    cache = get_distribution_cache(index, dist_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdistro/__init__.py", line 160, in get_distribution_cache
    yaml_gz_str = load_url(url, skip_decode=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdistro/loader.py", line 59, in load_url
    raise URLError(str(e) + ' (%s)' % url)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known> (http://ros.org/rosdistro/groovy-cache.yaml.gz)>
```

Please help me slove the problem,thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196376/error-while-installing-ros-from-source-on-ubuntu-arm/) by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're having network connectivity issues. Can you ping ros.org or fetch the failing URL manually?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on 2014-11-02**:
Thank you help me,too.I have already checked.The network connection is no problem.I can visit [www.ros.org](http://www.ros.org) on the arm.Meanwhile,I can  open this web site on the arm,http://ros.org/rosdistro/groovy-cache.yaml.gz.Please help me again.thank you very much

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-02**:
Can you ping ros.org from the command line? Try: `ping ros.org`

**Comment by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on 2014-11-02**:
Can not ping ros.org,but I can ping [www.ros.org](http://www.ros.org) on the arm

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-02**:
That sounds like there's something wrong with your network configuration. I don't have any specific advice, but once you get it figured out you should be able to proceed with your ROS installation.